# Anaconda: upgrading to 2018.12 and mkl error

Tags: python, anaconda, intel-mkl

I followed the upgrade instructions for the anaconda upgrade to the new 2018.12 version. As per the Anaconda announcement they are going to year and date version numbers. I am running Anaconda on ubuntu 16.04 x64.

So I did a `conda update conda` and then typed `conda install anaconda=2018.12`. However, I am getting an error about the `mkl` package:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda=2018.12 -> mkl==2019.1=144
  - suitesparse
```

I checked the dependencies for `mkl` but was not clear on what the problem is? Should I try and install a newer version of mkl?

Comment: It seems like the problem is that `anaconda=2018.12` requires `mkl=2019.1`, while `suitesparse` requires an older version of `mkl`. If you remove `suitesparse` it will probably solve this conflict.

Comment: @darthbith yep, seems like that is what was causing it. Thanks for the tip. Seems like there are other incompatibilities with some other packages, so I think I will wait a bit for those things to get straightened out. Thanks again.